# How can I format my equation of adding arbitrary values, better?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I am finalizing my dissertation and am struggling to get these algorithms to display correctly... I'm new to writing pseudocode in LaTeX too so any recommendations are VERY welcome.

[image: Array reordering, adding arbitrary values]

% Back Orientation
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        &B^{o}_c = (0, 2\{+1\}, 7\{+2\}, 3, 1\{+2\}, 5, 6, 4\{+1\}) \\
        &B^{o}_e = (0, 1, 7\{+1\}, 3, 2\{+1\}, 5, 6, 8\{+1\}, 4\{+1\}, 9, 10, 11)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
% Right Orientation
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        &R^{o}_c = (0, 1, 3\{+1\}, 6\{+2\}, 4, 5, 7\{+1\}, 2\{+2\}) \\
        &R^{o}_e = (0, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 11, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
% Left Orientation
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        &L^{o}_c = (1\{+1\}, 4\{+2\}, 2, 3, 5\{+1\}, 0\{+2\}, 6, 7) \\
        &L^{o}_e = (0, 4, 2, 3, 9, 1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 10, 11)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

> What would be the best way to format the array re-ordering with the addition of the arbitrary values?

You can see the curly brackets are there to "add" the arbitrary values of 1 and 2, although I don't think this is very clear. Does anyone have any suggestions? Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I was told in the LaTeX stack exchange this question was more suited to notation rather than LaTeX...

Comment: From the image hyperlinked there, what would be the best way to format the array re-ordering with the addition of the arbitrary values

Comment: OK, I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: I don't see curly brackets...

Comment: In the image.. Sorry I've pasted the wrong latex code. I'll repaste now.

Comment: What are your algorithms suppose to do?